# Debouncing based on $event

Tags: rxjs5, angular5

I'm interested in using rxjs5 in angular5 to debounce input, but using `$event` from, for example `keyup`, as opposed to using `valueChanged` and hard-assigning it to a component (as seems to be the case with so many examples).

In the example below, let's say I want to use `locsearchTerm` for further processing;

```
querySearchTerm(event){
  let searchTerm : Observable<string> = event.target.value;
  let locsearchTerm  =  searchTerm
                          .distinctUntilChanged()
                          .debounceTime(4000)
                          //... etc, etc
}
```

Despite the fact I'm binding to `(keyup)=querySearchTerm(event)` in my templates input element, and assigning `searchTerm` as an Observable string, the error `searchTerm.distinctUntilChanged is not a function` is returned.

Could someone explain why something like this doesn't work, and if possible provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a string into an Observable by writing

```
const obs$: Observable<string> = "Hello";
```

The type is only type information for Typescript and carries no logic. So that assignment won't magically turn your event into a stream (and besides, what good is a stream of a single event in this case?)

You need to create an Observable from the event stream that captures all events to the same stream:

```
// We use a subject to capture the events because a
// subject is both an observer and an observable, which
// means we can both subscribe to it and emit to it. 
private events$ = new Subject();

// Here you can subscribe to your observable and
// manipulate the stream. 
constructor() {
    this.events$
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .subscribe(event => console.log(event));
} 

// When we receive an event, just emit it on the subject.
// The subscription handles the rest. 
querySearchTerm(event) { 
    events$.next(event); 
}
```

If you have a reference to the DOM element you can also use

```
const events$ = Observable.fromEvent(input, "keyup");
```

to create the observable rather than doing it by hand.